# How to increase timeout for a single test case in mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm submitting a network request in a test case, but this sometimes takes longer than 2 seconds (the default timeout).

How do I increase the timeout for a single test case?

Answer (score 740):

Here you go: http://mochajs.org/#test-level

```
it('accesses the network', function(done){
  this.timeout(500);
  [Put network code here, with done() in the callback]
})
```

For arrow function use as follows:

```
it('accesses the network', (done) => {
  [Put network code here, with done() in the callback]
}).timeout(500);
```

Comment: timeout is in milliseconds, and it defaults 2000.

Comment: I was using es6 arrow functions and had to fall back to old 'function' definitions for "this" to work.

Comment: Do you have a simple example of this "[Put network code here, with done() in the callback]"?  This part confuses me.

Comment: Also works for hooks, like `before(function(done){this.timeout(5 * 1000);...});`

Comment: @AH The reason the arrow function didn't work is because of [lexical this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)

Comment: is there a way to get it to work with arrow function? edit: add `.timeout(500)` to end of `it(...).timeout(500)`

Comment: Mocha specifically discourages arrow functions: https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions. IMO it's worth pointing out in the answer.

Comment: doesn't work for me, getting a "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)" (no, I'm not using arrow functions)

Answer (score 159):

If you wish to use es6 arrow functions you can add a `.timeout(ms)` to the end of your `it` definition:

```
it('should not timeout', (done) => {
    doLongThing().then(() => {
        done();
    });
}).timeout(5000);
```

At least this works in Typescript.

Comment: This works, but `.timeout` is not included in the DefinitelyTyped typings for mocha: http://i.imgur.com/jQbWCn1.png - Using `this.timeout(2000)` or `this.slow(500)` with a regular old function works and compiles without errors

Comment: Sadly, this only works for `it`, it doesn't work for `describe`.

Comment: is there a way to do this for `describe()` or `context()`?

Comment: @LeonAdler `.timeout` is now included in DefinitelyTyped's Mocha typings at: `Mocha.IRunnable`. However, if you're using the Webstorm IDE for running these tests, a note of caution: for whatever reason, WebStorm's Mocha integration plugin still does not recognise Mocha tests with `.timeout()` appended (meaning that no 'run' button appears next to them), and thus I advocate avoiding arrow functions to allow use of `this.timeout()` instead.

Comment: This is perfect. For async function returning a promise you can leave out done().

Comment: This also doesn't work for `it.only()`. You have to `describe.only()` if you want to use `.timeout()` with `it`

Comment: If you have a promise, it's easier to `return doLongThing().then(...)` and remove the `done` stuff entirely.

Answer (score 77):

*(since I ran into this today)*

Be careful when using ES2015 fat arrow syntax:

**This will fail :**

```
it('accesses the network', done => {

  this.timeout(500); // will not work

  // *this* binding refers to parent function scope in fat arrow functions!
  // i.e. the *this* object of the describe function

  done();
});
```

**EDIT: Why it fails:**

As @atoth mentions in the comments, *fat arrow* functions do not have their own *this* binding. Therefore, it's not possible for the *it* function to bind to *this* of the callback and provide a *timeout* function.

*Bottom line*: Don't use arrow functions for functions that need an increased timeout.

Comment: Because arrow functions does not have this at all. Read more here: https://blog.getify.com/arrow-this/

Comment: Yes but I have explained this in the answer. See my comment. // inside the code. I should probably explain it outside the code block to make it clearer. this does exist but it comes from the outer scope.

Comment: My explanation is more accurate. There is no `this` binding on arrow functions - not the same way would suggest they have some kind of, just different. They only have lexical scopes. You can't bind non-existing this. That's why `.bind`, `.call`, etc. does not work with it.

Comment: That's true - and your right it's more accurate. Thanks

Comment: I'd say that this is why you should only use fat arrows when you need them, but I've lost track of what `this` is.

Comment: _Bottom line:_ Don't use `this`.

Answer (score 58):

If you are using in NodeJS then you can set timeout in package.json

```
"test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
```

then you can run using npm like:

```
npm test
```

Comment: That's for all test cases, not a single test case

Comment: Agreed that this doesn't answer the question, but it was sufficient for my use case where I didn't care if it increased for all tests. I think a lot of people who end up here may not care if it's for one test or all, so I appreciate this answer being here.

Answer (score 25):

From command line:

```
mocha -t 100000 test.js
```

Comment: This increases the timeout *for all test cases* rather than "for a particular test case" like the question asks.

Answer (score 17):

You might also think about taking a different approach, and replacing the call to the network resource with a stub or mock object. Using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), you can decouple the app from the network service, focusing your development efforts.

Comment: It's not *entirely* irrelevant; frequently, it makes sense to stub the network response so you're not reliant on that machine being up or returning the correct response. If you're testing the response itself, however, then yeah, you still need to do it.

Comment: I'm using sinon/mocha to build some integration tests, so higher timeouts are relevant.

Answer (score 15):

**For test navigation on `Express`:**

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('../bin/www');

describe('navigation', () => {
    it('login page', function(done) {
        this.timeout(4000);
        const timeOut = setTimeout(done, 3500);

        request(server)
            .get('/login')
            .expect(200)
            .then(res => {
                res.text.should.include('Login');
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(this.test.fullTitle(), err);
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
                done(err);
            });
    });
});
```

In the example the test time is 4000 (4s).

Note: `setTimeout(done, 3500)` is minor for than `done` is called within the time of the test but `clearTimeout(timeOut)` it avoid than used all these time.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me! Couldn't find anything to make it work with before()

```js
describe("When in a long running test", () => {
  it("Should not time out with 2000ms", async () => {
    let service = new SomeService();
    let result = await service.callToLongRunningProcess();
    expect(result).to.be.true;
  }).timeout(10000); // Custom Timeout 
});
```