# how to test showing an element after a click?

Tags: javascript, meteor, mocha.js, mocha-web-velocity

I'm working with mocha unit test and I need to test if an element is visible after click on a radio button. In other words I have two radio buttons that toggle two elements using javascript and I would like to test this.

this is my test:

```
it("Checking #completed-task existance", function (done) {
    chai.assert.equal($("#completed-task").length, 1);
    done();
});

it("Checking #completed-task is visible", function (done) {
    $("#master div.onoffswitch").find("input[data-id='completed-task']").click();
    chai.assert.equal($("#completed-task").is(":visible"), true);
});
```

the first test passes but the second one doesn't. the problem is that `$("#completed-task").is(":visible")` is always false, in the actual page this works just fine, any suggestions?

Comment: Try calling `Tracker.flush();` between the two lines in your test.  Does that help?

Comment: Otherwise it would help to see your code that handles the 'click' event.

Comment: @colllin it didn't work :-(
this is my js code http://pastebin.com/axrZWJiK (relevant code) and this is my template http://pastebin.com/p3f8ApRX

Answer (score -1):

You've got an animation on the element that is being shown / hidden.  You need to put your assertion after a timeout.  Since you're only checking if it's ':visible', you don't need to wait for the entire animation to complete.  I would start with 100ms (or even 0ms) and then see if you need more.

For example:

```
it("Checking #completed-task is visible", function (done) {
    $("#master div.onoffswitch").find("input[data-id='completed-task']").click();

    // This may be needed to increase the mocha timeout.        
    //this.timeout(100);

    setTimeout(function() {
        chai.assert.equal($("#completed-task").is(":visible"), true);
        done();
    }, 100);
});
```

This answer has more details and a link to docs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982893/361609

Comment: it didn't work :-( I even tried with `done()` and `this.timeout(10000)` . I also tried something like this http://pastebin.com/7EdA5jc5 . the first `console.log()` is displayed but the sencond one isn't. that makes me think that the program get lost somewhere inside the click event...

Comment: Well, now your second function is being bound as a click handler, right?  Not calling the click method.  So you're no longer triggering a click.

Comment: I don't know enough about Mocha to help you, but if you think your code is working right, then the problem is that the test is checking the `':visible'` state of the element before the animation has had a chance to make it visible.  You need to figure out how to delay the check until after the animation has started.

Comment: This example might be helpful too: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/17/asynchronous-unit-tests-with-mocha-promises-and-winjs/

Comment: @juanp_1982 Did you see these comments?

Comment: Hi $collin thanks for you help, I also tried what you suggested in you pastebin and I never get to see the second message, I even increase the time to `this.timeout(10000);` and didn't work, my guess is that faking a click is disrupting the app

Comment: `timeout` increases the allowed timeout, but does not seem to cause the script to "wait".

Comment: @Luke Then do you need to put the assertion in a setTimeout?  See updated answer.