# Testing for className's CSS using Enzyme/React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, unit-testing, chai, enzyme

I can't find how to check the CSS of a div in my react component.

You can check inline styles ([How can I test React component's style with Jest + Enzyme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055712/how-can-i-test-react-components-style-with-jest-enzyme?noredirect=1&lq=1))
 But this doesn't let me check my `className='App-header'` of my component.

I have successfully added `chai-jquery`, however I don't know how to get my component to fully load, I only get `<body></body` returned.

**Answering 1 of 3 will solve my problem:**

**1. How can I test/check the class CSS of my div that I find using `expect(wrapper.find('#id'))...` without having the `<div>`'s CSS as an inline style.**

**2. How can I make sure my full component renders because right now jquery only returns `<body></body>`, but my chai/enzyme returns my full component by using `shallow(<App />)`?**

**3. Is there a way to test CSS style sheets? MAybe this is a workaround.**

.

```
it('should have a header with display: block', (done)=>{
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

        const body = $('body')
        console.log(body) // Returns <body></body>
        expect(body).exist; // Returns true
        expect(body).to.have.css('display', 'block'); //nothing in body, doesn't work

        expect(wrapper.find('#body').get(0).props).to.have.property({display: 'block'}) //not in the props because CSS comes from className 

        done()
    })
```

References:

Failed attempt using assert ([how to test showing an element after a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158945/how-to-test-showing-an-element-after-a-click))

Great Ideas but require inline styles ([How to test style for a React component attribute with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795850/how-to-test-style-for-a-react-component-attribute-with-enzyme))

Comment: do you want to check that ```body``` has a class App-header and this class contains ```display: block``` as style in it ?

Comment: basically. I would like to just see if the body which has App-header class has anywhere in it a `display: block`, but I can also double check the class. But if I do this I may as well just make sure the class is present since I will know the CSS for that class. If there are other classes though, I want the test to look at those classes that the body has too

Answer (score 2):

In order to render the whole component into a DOM, you need to call `enzyme.mount(<Component/>)`. When a `global.document` and a `global.window` are defined (like from jsdom), Enzyme can render your component into a mocked DOM. You can then call `wrapper.getDOMNode()` to get a wrapper's underlying DOM element. For example:

```
import jsdom from "jsdom";
import {mount} from "enzyme";

const dom = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = dom;
global.window = dom.defaultView;

it('should have a header with display: block', (done)=>{
    const wrapper = mount(<App />); // note `mount()`, not `shallow()`. 

    expect(wrapper.find('#body').get(0).getDOMNode().getComputedStyle()).to.have.property({display: 'block'})  

    done()
})
```

However, as it currently stands, `jsdom` will not pull in external stylesheets---although support for `<style/>` tags was recently added, but instead of testing for styles, it might make more sense to check for a specific element, like a `<h1/>` or a `<h2/>`.

Comment: Thank you, I have heard from a few people maybe testing for styles doesn't make sense. Although I will try getDOMNode() and getComputedStyle(), thank you!

Comment: Also, another useful technique is snapshot testing -- basically diffing the output of a component with the last version. It helps to avoid writing finicky test cases checking for individual elements and the like that have to be updated every version.

Comment: `getDOMNode` was not a function, any idea why? Also, is it necessary to specify your jsdom like that, I had mine set to jsdom.jsdom('') but changed it when I saw yours